# How to save tweaked password to browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, passwords

In my application, while logging in browser asked me to save password.
To prevent that I used html tag autocomplete = "off" and it is not working for some browser.

For a more step security - If browser asked to save password, Password should get changed while saving the password in browse.

For that on click of login, I fetch the password from field and then changed the password with dummy password using javascript.

Code  :

```
function onLoginClick(){
       var passStr = $("#myPassword").val();
       $("#myPassword").val('dummyPassword');
}
```

But while saving password, Browser is picking up the actual password not that dummy password.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Chrome keeps track of the last user-entered value of each input. So, simply swapping it out isn't going to overwrite that. What you may want to do is call listen for the `submit` event, and call the event's `preventDefault` function in your handler. I'm not sure exactly what each browser is looking for to trigger the "wanna save this password?" dialog, but I know that navigating away in the submit tick is one of them. Have you tried something along the lines of:

```
<form>
    <input name="username">
    <input type="password" name="textPass">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenPass">
</form>
```

with the js:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    if(hiddenPass.value.length === 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        hiddenPass.value = textPass.value;
        textPass.value = '';
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            form.submit();
        });
    }
});
```

Or what about an invisible password field?:

```
<input type="password" name="password" value="" style="display: none;">
<input type="password" name="realPassword">
```

Comment: I am not using form, I simply calling js function for execution. I had seen that in many banking portal while loging in, password get salted on sumbit action and store password prompt also pick that salted password.